How to add missed query param in NextJs URL in Server Component (Page)?
I have a NextJS page :

const Page = async ({ params, searchParams }: Props) => {
  const result = await getData({ params, searchParams })

  const {tab,slp,electricity}=searchParams

  // How to add the query param if it's missed with default value

  const { image, roofSurfaces } = result

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <NavigationTabs image={image} roofs={roofSurfaces} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default Page


I want to check if these query params are available, otherwise, I'll add them with default values
